# TypeError: i.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a question, I am developing an application with Vuejs and I need to export files of any type (pdf, txt, xlsx), but no matter what, I always get this error when I try to use this function, I put a simple example of a file that should be able to download as a test:

```
  var blob = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
  saveAs(blob, 'hello.txt')
```

the saveAs function I get it from the 'file-saver' library.

Edit

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <Button @click="export">Export</Button>
</template>
```

I simply have a button that calls the export function

```
 export: function () {
      var blob = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
      saveAs(blob, 'hello.txt')
 },
```

I just realized that this works fine when in production, but not in the local environment. Why does this happen?

Comment: The error is probably not coming from the given snippet. Also, I'm not sure VueJS is able to save to a filesystem, quite sure actually.

Comment: You're right @kissu, Vue can't download to the file system, but this type of action utilizes the browser APIs which allows it to generate a file from the blob and download that file to the downloads folder, just like any other file that gets downloaded in the browser. This problem doesn't really relate to Vue like the tag suggests.

Comment: @Daniel You would have to share a piece of your actual code for us to be able to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I added the code I have, but it is really very simple. I would just hope that the function generates something and doesn't return the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking for a possible solution I found that the problem is this function:

```
URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

No matter how I use it, either directly or through a library the error was always here. The way I solved it was by changing the previous function for this one:

```
window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

At least this worked for me, I hope it can help someone else who has the same problem.

Comment: Does it work on Firefox?

Comment: @kissu I just checked it, it works